# using CefSharp WPF with MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, cefsharp

I am using CefSharp WPF control in project with MVVM Light. I try to show ProgessRing, when browser loads new page. So I bind two commands, to suitable events and get an error. Is it my fault or it's a problem of CefSharp or MVVM? See following code.

```
 <wpf:ChromiumWebBrowser 
        Address="{Binding Url, Mode=OneWay}" 
        x:Name="cwbDescription"
        Grid.Row="0" 
        Grid.RowSpan="14" 
        Grid.Column="3"
        ZoomLevel="{Binding BrowserZoom, Mode=OneWay}"
        Visibility="{Binding IsReadOnly, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVis}, FallbackValue=Hidden}"
        Tag="{Binding}">
        <i:Interaction.Triggers>
            <i:EventTrigger EventName="Loaded">
                <command:EventToCommand Command="{Binding BrowserLoadedCommand, Mode=TwoWay}" PassEventArgsToCommand="True"/>
            </i:EventTrigger>
            <i:EventTrigger EventName="FrameLoadStart">
                <command:EventToCommand Command="{Binding FrameLoadStartCommand}" PassEventArgsToCommand="True"/>
            </i:EventTrigger>
            <i:EventTrigger EventName="FrameLoadEnd">
                <command:EventToCommand Command="{Binding FrameLoadEndCommand}" PassEventArgsToCommand="True"/>
            </i:EventTrigger>
        </i:Interaction.Triggers>
    </wpf:ChromiumWebBrowser> 

    <controls:ProgressRing IsActive="{Binding IsDownloadInProgress}" IsLarge="True" Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="0" Grid.RowSpan="14" />

...

    private ICommand _frameLoadStartCommand;
    private ICommand _frameLoadEndCommand;
...

    public ICommand FrameLoadStartCommand
    {
        get { return this._frameLoadStartCommand; }
        set { Set(() => FrameLoadStartCommand, ref this._frameLoadStartCommand, value); }
    }

    public ICommand FrameLoadEndCommand
    {
        get { return this._frameLoadEndCommand; }
        set { Set(() => FrameLoadEndCommand, ref this._frameLoadEndCommand, value); }
    }
...
    FrameLoadStartCommand = new RelayCommand<FrameLoadStartEventArgs>(FrameLoadStart, x => true);
    FrameLoadEndCommand = new RelayCommand<FrameLoadEndEventArgs>(FrameLoadEnd, x => true);

...
    private void FrameLoadStart(FrameLoadStartEventArgs args)
    {
        IsDownloadInProgress = true;
    }

    private void FrameLoadEnd(FrameLoadEndEventArgs args)
    {
        IsDownloadInProgress = false;
    }
```

And as result I get this error

```
2016-06-14 10:53:32.303 HomeCinema.ApplicationOne.MainWindow2::current domain unhandled exception object: System.InvalidOperationException: The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it.
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.VerifyAccess()
   at System.Windows.DependencyObject.GetValue(DependencyProperty dp)
   at System.Windows.Interactivity.TriggerBase.get_Actions()
   at System.Windows.Interactivity.TriggerBase.InvokeActions(Object parameter)
   at CefSharp.Wpf.ChromiumWebBrowser.CefSharp.Internals.IWebBrowserInternal.OnFrameLoadStart(FrameLoadStartEventArgs args)
   at CefSharp.Internals.ClientAdapter.OnLoadStart(ClientAdapter* , CefRefPtr<CefBrowser>* browser, CefRefPtr<CefFrame>* frame) 
 exception: System.InvalidOperationException: The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it.
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.VerifyAccess()
   at System.Windows.DependencyObject.GetValue(DependencyProperty dp)
   at System.Windows.Interactivity.TriggerBase.get_Actions()
   at System.Windows.Interactivity.TriggerBase.InvokeActions(Object parameter)
   at CefSharp.Wpf.ChromiumWebBrowser.CefSharp.Internals.IWebBrowserInternal.OnFrameLoadStart(FrameLoadStartEventArgs args)
   at CefSharp.Internals.ClientAdapter.OnLoadStart(ClientAdapter* , CefRefPtr<CefBrowser>* browser, CefRefPtr<CefFrame>* frame) 
 stack trace;    at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.VerifyAccess()
   at System.Windows.DependencyObject.GetValue(DependencyProperty dp)
   at System.Windows.Interactivity.TriggerBase.get_Actions()
   at System.Windows.Interactivity.TriggerBase.InvokeActions(Object parameter)
   at CefSharp.Wpf.ChromiumWebBrowser.CefSharp.Internals.IWebBrowserInternal.OnFrameLoadStart(FrameLoadStartEventArgs args)
   at CefSharp.Internals.ClientAdapter.OnLoadStart(ClientAdapter* , CefRefPtr<CefBrowser>* browser, CefRefPtr<CefFrame>* frame)
```

Comment: Those events are invoked on a different thread as the exception. `ChromiumWebBriwser` already has quite a number of `DependencyProperties`, in your case just bind to `IsLoading` https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/blob/master/CefSharp.Wpf/ChromiumWebBrowser.cs#L531

Comment: https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp.MinimalExample/blob/master/CefSharp.MinimalExample.Wpf/MainWindow.xaml#L5 show another method of using properties in bindings. As a general note the `CefSharp.Wpf.Example` project does use the `MvvmLightLibs` package, it's not the model `MVVM` example, lots of it should give you ideas on how to work with the project though. I'd suggest writing a few custom `IValueConverter`'s.

Comment: Thank your for advice. I bind ProgressRing to IsLoading dependency property and that helped.

Comment: Great. If your new to `WPF` and threading then I'd suggest you do some background reading, something like https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn630646.aspx might help.

Comment: you can refer to my answer on this post [cefsharp load wait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53160587/cefsharp-how-to-check-of-all-java-script-in-page-are-completed/53275208#53275208)

Comment: @amaitland, I have also tried IsLoading property of ChromiumWebBrowser. Still I am facing "The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it" in the ViewModel class file (MVVM). Could you please provide an answer for this question?