# cefsharp how to check of all java script in page are completed?

Tags: c#, cefsharp

Iam using CefSharp browser and c# .

i try login to page but when i click the submit button the page didnt refresh untill login sucess and if not the page load in server and get message password error

How i can Check if all java script in page after i submit ?

```
//Initialize ChromiumWebBrowser
Chromium = new ChromiumWebBrowser("www.exapmle.com/login");

        this.panel2.Controls.Add(chrom);
        Chromium.Show();
        Chromium.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
```

click submit button
var cvbar = chrom.EvaluateScriptAsync("document.getElementById(\"login_u\");

I want Here To check if all javascript completed 
 something like this

```
 if(javascripteCompleted()
 {
        var response = cvbar.Result;
        if (response.Success == true && response.Result.ToString() != "")
        {
          //  MessageBox.Show(response.Result.ToString());
        }
  }
```

thanks

Comment: There is no universal measure for when javascript has finished execution, each website behaves differently. I don't recommend trying to return `DOM Elements`, you should just return the value of the element. Past that I don't have a clear picture of what you are actually trying to do.

Comment: i try to login website using Cefsharp the problem is when you enter your id and password the page excuting query on server it's take a litle time then show you "invalid login " or "Suceess login" whithout page refresh Hope you understand Thanks

Comment: Still doesn't explain what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is what i did to show webpage only when its loaded and until then show SPINNER

```
private void Cefbrowser_LoadingStateChanged(object sender, LoadingStateChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!e.IsLoading)
        {
            Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(delegate
            {
                myspin.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
            });

        }
    }
```

my XAML code

```
<StackPanel Name="panel">
            <Grid VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" MinHeight="700" Height="{Binding ElementName=panel,Path=ActualHeight}" Name="maingrid">
                <fa:ImageAwesome Name="myspin" Icon="Spinner" Spin="True" SpinDuration="4" Height="80" />
            </Grid>
        </StackPanel>
```

initally i put a fontawesome spinner which shows that the page is loading when the loading state changes `if (!e.IsLoading)` is fullfilled, then the spinner goes into the background and webWINDOW is loaded like this: -

```
chrome.Load(URL);
```

**FYI Loading_State_Changed works when entire page html + javascript + css loads **